# Android Studio Appodeal Api 19 or lower

Tags: java, android, api, libgdx

It seems that I can't get Appodeal to run on API 19 or lower because it crashes on launch. On API 22 it works just fine. Do you know if there is a problem between Appodeal and API 19 or lower?

Answer (score 0):

Api 19 should work fine with Appodeal SDK. Could you attach log of crash?